# Can't use functions exported from .bashrc in a bash script

Tags: bash, bashrc

My `.bashrc` file exports a function called `lookup`:

```
lookup() {
  grep -r -ne "$1" * | grep -v "TAGS:" | grep -v "tags:"
}
export -f lookup
```

I can use that function in a shell.  But if I put it in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lookup "foo"
```

and run the script then bash reports "command not found" for `lookup`.  This used to work some time ago.  I strongly suspect this is stopped working after a security update of bash on my system (possibly related to shellshock/bashdoor?) My bash version is 4.1.10(1) on openSUSE 11.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

> **Invoked non-interactively**
>
> When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.

Specifically, none of the ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile are NOT sourced. ~/.bashrc is only invoked if the shell is an interactive shell.

You have a couple of options:

1. source your .bashrc explicitly

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   . ~/.bashrc
   lookup "foo"
   ```
2. start bash with the interactive flag

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -i
   lookup "foo"
   ```
3. set the BASH_ENV variable when you start your script:

   ```
   BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc /path/to/my/script
   ```

Comment: For some reason advice no. 2 does not work if I invoke the script via `./foo.sh`. It only works if I invoke via `bash foo.sh`. But advice no. 1 works flawlessly.